# hadoop sqoop export table to sql server error

Tags: shell, hadoop, sqoop, sql-server-2014

I am new to hadoop and have recently started work on sqoop. While trying to export a table from hadoop to sql server i am getting the following error:
input path does not exist hdfs://sandbox:8020/user/root/
The command i am using is :
sqoop export --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://;username=;password=xxxxx;database=" --table  --export-dir /user/root/ -input-fields-terminated-by " "
Could you please guide what i am missing here.
Also could you please let me know the command to navigate to the hadoop directory where the tables are stored.

Answer (score 0):

For a proper sqoop export, Sqoop requires the complete data file location. You cant just specify the root folder.

Try specifying the complete src path

```
   sqoop export --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:<>:1521/<> --username <> --password <> --table <>  --export-dir hdfs://<>/user/<>/<> -m 1 --input-fields-terminated-by '|' --input-null-string '\\N' --input-null-non-string '\\N'
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i think you need to add --columns ID,value1,value2,.. after --table <> as a example    `sqoop export --connect jdbc:sqlserver://{some.ip.address};database={somedatabase} / --username 'someuser' /
--password-file '/some/password/file' /
--table 'Sometable' /
--columns ID,value1,value2 /
--export-dir /apps/hive/warehouse/some.db/Sometable /
--input-fields-terminated-by "||" / -m 2 /`